# Use Google Places Library to show all location markers for a predetermined keyword with Google Maps and Ionic

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, google-places-api, google-places

I want to display a marker for each Place search result on my map but it doesn't work.

---EDIT---

I have tried to debug figure out what I am missing and why the markers are not showing up, but I am not able to figure it out. Even if the answer is very obvious, I might not be able to see it with what I currently have. I had edited the code a little bit with the setMarker() function and the options of the marker to be displayed on the map created, but that does not seem to be the answer to why the markers wont show up. I shouldn't have to create markers at specific Latitudes and Longitudes but instead search the area around the current location using a predetermined search keyword which in this case would be "McDonalds" (this search keyword is being used for testing).

map.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Map
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id='map'>
  </div>
    <ion-fab bottom right id="locate">
      <button ion-fab
      (click)="locationClick()" color="white"><ion-icon ios="ios-locate-outline" md ="md-locate" color="primary"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab>
    <ion-fab top left id="compass-fab">
      <button ion-fab mini (click)="compassClick()" color="white" id="compass"></button>
    </ion-fab>
    <ion-fab top right id="layers">
      <button ion-fab mini id="layers-button" color="white"><ion-icon name="SMAPP-layers"></ion-icon></button>
      <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
        <button ion-fab mini (click)="trafficClick()" id="traffic" color="white"></button>
        <button ion-fab mini (click)="transitClick()" id="transit" color="white"></button>
        <button ion-fab mini (click)="bicycleClick()" id="bicycle" color="white"></button>
      </ion-fab-list>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

map.ts:

```
   declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})
export class OfficeLocatorPage {
  @ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  mapOptions:any;
  infowindow: any;
  trafficEnabled = false;
  transitEnabled = false;
  bicycleEnabled = false;
  markers = [];
  trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
  bicycleLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform,
  private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
      this.navCtrl.pop({animate: true, animation: "transition", direction: "left", duration: 300});
    };
 }
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }

  locationClick() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
    let myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
    this.map.setCenter(myLocation);
  });
}

  compassClick() {
    this.map.animateCamera({
      target: this.map.getCameraTarget(),
      tilt: 0,
      bearing: 0,
      duration: 1000
    });
  }

  trafficClick() {
    if (this.transitEnabled == true) {
      this.transitClick();
      this.trafficEnabled = true;
      this.trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);
    } else if (this.trafficEnabled == false) {
      this.trafficEnabled = true;
      this.trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);
    } else {
      this.trafficEnabled = false;
      this.trafficLayer.setMap(null);
    }
  }
  transitClick() {
    if (this.trafficEnabled == true) {
      this.trafficClick();
      this.transitEnabled = true;
      this.transitLayer.setMap(this.map);
    } else if (this.transitEnabled == false) {
      this.transitEnabled = true;
      this.transitLayer.setMap(this.map);
    } else {
      this.transitEnabled = false;
      this.transitLayer.setMap(null);
    }
  }
  bicycleClick() {
    this.bicycleEnabled = !this.bicycleEnabled;
    if (this.bicycleEnabled) {
      this.bicycleLayer.setMap(this.map);
    } else {
      this.bicycleLayer.setMap(null);
    }
  }


  loadMap() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
    let myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: myLocation,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });
  });
  let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
  watch.subscribe((data) => {
    this.deleteMarkers();
    let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
    let image = {
      url: "assets/icon/blue_dot.png", // url
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 33), // scaled size
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // ancho
    };
    this.addMarker(updatelocation, image);
    this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
  });
    var request = {
      query: 'McDonalds',
      fields: ['photos', 'formatted_address', 'name', 'rating', 'opening_hours', 'geometry'],
    };
    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, callback);
    function callback(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          let placeLoc = results[i].geometry.location;
          this.addMarker(placeLoc, 'red');
        }
      }
      this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
    }
  }

  addMarker(location, image) {
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: this.map,
    icon: image
  });
  this.markers.push(marker);
}

setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
    this.markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

clearMarkers() {
  this.setMapOnAll(null);
}

deleteMarkers() {
  this.clearMarkers();
  this.markers = [];
}
}
```

Comment: The bounty ends tomorrow and I am still unsure of how to fix this. I believe that the issue is because of how I set the map variable to the return value of GoogleMaps.create() (which is from the GoogleMaps module from ionic) instead of the google.maps.Map return value. I have tried it using the JavaScript API documentation for Google Maps, but I still come up short on how to fix the issue. If there is anyone who can help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that the places library was not being accessed correctly but is now, I have also updated the code to show what needs to be done to gather information using the places function, findPlaceByQuery(). The Google JavaScript API Documentation is not accurate in how to display search results based on a query. Here is the updated code on how to do it, once you have the Places Library set up correctly in the script tag to be used (I have also included the code on how to correctly display the markers, scopeObj is the class object passed into the loadMap() function):

map.ts:

```
  var request ={
        locationBias: this.myLocation,
        query: "McDonalds",
        fields: ['photos', 'formatted_address', 'name', 'rating', 'opening_hours', 'geometry']
      };
      var callbackCount = 0;
      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            let placeLoc = results[i].geometry.location;
            scopeObj.addMarker(placeLoc, 'red');
          }
        }
        callbackCount++;
      };
      let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
      service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, callback);
      continueExec();

      function continueExec() {
        if (callbackCount < 1) {
          setTimeout(continueExec, 1000);
          return;
        }
        scopeObj.setMapOnAll(this.map);
      }
  }

    addMarker(location, image) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: this.map,
      icon: image
    });
    this.markers.push(marker);
  }

  setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: this.markers[i].getPosition(),
          map: this.map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }
  }
```

Places API script to be added into index.html above all other script tags in the  tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=....&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to you use `setMap(map);`. There is a good example that you will utilize  [from](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a48517280aca7059c142972/ionic-3-angular-5-firebase-and-google-maps-location-tracking). I used it couple month before and works perfect. Hope it helps.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and I will try it out. My question will that code to finding location and setting a marker at location finally allow the google places code (starting at "var request") to work correctly?

Comment: I completely followed the documentation, but there are no markers showing up for the search query using the places API. Is there anything I need to change with that part of my code. I updated my code to show what I have so far.

Comment: I have found that from the documentation from the link you posted, the Google Maps JavaScript API is not very smooth compared to the Cordova Google Maps module. It may take a second or two to load or the map may never load when I open up the app. Is there anyway to use the Places API directly with the Google Maps module from cordova or is it still being developed?